# Auto Grouping/Merging in Excel

Tags: excel, merge, grouping

I think the image attached describes better than I can in words the functionality I am trying to locate within excel.

Is there a way to auto group based on the contents within the columns as shown? This is achievable for the example shown, but when there are up to say 30 Groups and many sub group types, I am wondering whether excel can auto-detect and work its way through the list, grouping as shown as it goes.

[image]

Comment: Excel does not have a native function to do this.  It will need to be programmed through vba.

Comment: Are you looking to merge the cells or do you want to group the rows with the plus and minus buttons to show and hide the rows?  If's possible to do either with some VBA code.  It may be worth noting that merging the cells will make it more difficult to sort, filter and generally use the data in excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks. Are there any examples similar you may be able to share as my Excel VBA knowledge doesn't extend this far

Answer (score 8):

You can get a similar result using conditional formatting.  select the whole table and create a new conditional format rule and choose formula and enter =A1=A2 set the format font to white (I've used very light grey to show that the data is still there)

To get the borders, do the same again and this time enter the formula =A1<>A2 and make the top border black.

It's not exactly the same as yours but it's close.

[image: Grouping example]

Comment: This formula will keep the one close to the center: `=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=INT(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)/2)+1` in place of your `=A1=A2`

Comment: It's a good idea but it's not working for me.  The formula should work for "Group 1" but beyond that the count does not match the row number so it may need the row() to be added somewhere to get it working.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I added row() to the formula and it seems work (don't ask me how).  It only works on the A column range so column B will need it's own formula with B instead of A. =COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)+ROW()<>INT(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)/2)+ROW()

Comment: Sorry it should be `=AND(NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=INT(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)/2)),COUNTIF(A:A,A1)<>1)`

Comment: Lets try this again, I got this to work: `=AND(NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=INT(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)/2)+1),COUNTIF(A:A,A1)<>1)`  see: http://imgur.com/a/X0YtG

Comment: I got it working for column A but because Column B duplicates the entries "Type A" it throws off the count.

Comment: you are correct I missed that it uses the same type.  It will not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks for this, this looks promising although I accept the limitation in column B. I can't get it to work in column A, I've applied the conditional format to the whole of column A, is this correct? Or do I need only to apply it to A1?