# Merging duplicate column data without losing the values in the rest of the rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, merge, duplicates

I'm trying to find a way to merge duplicate values in the first column of my data without losing the unique values in the rest of the rows.

e.g. at the moment my data looks like this:

[image: column a with a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c and column b with 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

and I want it to look like this:

[image: column a with a, b, c and column b with 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

Comment: see here for a method that uses conditional formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938249/auto-grouping-merging-in-excel/41939842#comment71061510_41939842

Comment: @ScottCraner That was a good answer by Gordon.  I'll have to put that in my toolbox.  For this case, LucyG could simply make the font color white.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to focus only on the first column. The second has nothing to do with it.
Here is some pseudo code, that would work, if you translate it to VBA:

```
FOR EACH CELL IN COLUMN NUMBER
    IF CELL = OFFSET(PREVIOUS CELL) AND CELL.COLUMN > 1 THEN
        CELL.TEXT = ""
    END IF
NEXT CELL

FOR EACH CELL IN COLUMN NUMBER
    IF CELL = "" THEN 
        ENLARGE THE RANGE
    ELSE
        MERGE THE RANGE
    END IF
NEXT CELL

IF RANGE <> NOTHING THEN
     MERGE THE RANGE
END IF
```

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but be careful, I have seen pseudo code answers down voted, heavily.

Comment: @ScottCraner, Nothing can get more than 5 downvotes. :)